# Terraform build APIgateway2 authoriser jwt configuration using AWS SSM parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, aws-ssm

I am creating an AWS http APIgateway with JWT authorisation from cognito using Terraform.

I have built this out, using one app client and it works.
But i would like to add another app client. i call the clientid from AWS SSM.
below is the jwt_configuration extract from the module we have built.
extprovider is passed from the main resource tf as a variable.

eg extprovider=production

```
jwt_configuration {
      audience = [ data.aws_ssm_parameter.clientid.value  ] 
      issuer   =  data.aws_ssm_parameter.user_pool_endpoint.value  
  }
```

my data.tf

```
data aws_ssm_parameter clientid {
  name = "/${var.workflow}/cognito/${var.extprovider}/clientid"
}
```

The new setup will have the extprovider name of production_odd and production_even, this part must be done within the module, as the name of production is used elsewhere.

i had thought my approach would be;

```
locals {
extprovider_new  = flatten([ for e in var.extprovider : tolist(["${e}odd","${e}even"])])

}
```

```
data aws_ssm_parameter clientid1 {
  name = "/${var.workflow}/cognito/${var.extprovider_new[0]}/clientid"
}
data aws_ssm_parameter clientid2 {
  name = "/${var.workflow}/cognito/${var.extprovider_new[1]}/clientid"
}
```

```
jwt_configuration {
      audience = [ data.aws_ssm_parameter.clientid1.value,data.aws_ssm_parameter.clientid2.value  ] 
      issuer   =  data.aws_ssm_parameter.user_pool_endpoint.value  
  }
```

However, i am getting the error;

```
Error: Iteration over non-iterable value

  on ../modules/apiresource/locals.tf line 3, in locals:
   3: extprovider_new  = flatten([ for e in var.extprovider : tolist(["${e}odd","${e}even"])])
    ├────────────────
    │ var.extprovider is "foo"

A value of type string cannot be used as the collection in a 'for' expression.

Error: Iteration over non-iterable value

  on ../modules/apiresource/locals.tf line 3, in locals:
   3: extprovider_new  = flatten([ for e in var.extprovider : tolist(["${e}odd","${e}even"])])
    ├────────────────
    │ var.extprovider is "bar"

A value of type string cannot be used as the collection in a 'for' expression.
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Variable is a string, it needs to be a list;

````
   extprovider_new  = ["${var.extprovider}odd", "${var.extprovider}even"]
}```
````